# Print [object HTMLElement] in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, components

Lets say i want to print a variable that i create dinamicly with HTML syntax. In my HTML i want to print the new HTML but i dont know how.

If i print the variable in the HTML, it would print it like a Text.

This is the HTML i want to print:

```
this.content = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('sys-tab-content');
```

but if i print this:

```
<div>
  {{content[0]}}
</div>
```

it would just print the text and not like a HTML

**EDIT**
I just want to print this object inside my HTML, excatly as it is.. but When i print it, it just prints what i told you: [object HTMLElement]

Is there a way for me to print this Elements, i know it is not HTML but components.

i[image: Console log]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want one of

```
{{content && content[0].innerText}}
{{content && content[0].innerHTML}}
```

Comment: When i console.log content[0] has exactly what i want to print and when i put the innertext or innerhtml it doesnt print everything

Comment: It depends on where your code is. Check if you get an error in the browser console. I updated my answer so that it doesn't cause an error when `content` is not yet set. If you have the code in the constructor, move it to `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: content is set. When i print content[0] it prints [object HTMLElement]... I change the printing as you told me but it stil prints all the HTML but as text

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-2-html-binding/41089093#41089093

Comment: @yurzui that might be. I interpreted it so that he wants to get the text. As long as he doesn't bind to `innerHTML` I think it should add the content as text. Because it's quite unclear what the content is that he expects it's diffcult to tell.

Comment: @HelySaulOberto I don't see a way to provide support with the provided information. It's entirely unclear what the problem is and what behavior you expect. I think this requires at least a clear example to reproduce in Plunker or similar to investigate.

Comment: Lately there are a lot of strange questions. So i agree that it's hard to predict what he had in mind

Comment: @HelySaulOberto that doesn't really help.